# Is there any option to enable glm math operator overrides or is mistake on my side?

Tags: c++, glm-math

Im working on COLLADA format importer for my code, i have deserialized `glm::mat4` and my position, now i want to multiply them in code, but im getting error that binary operator is not specified. Is there any define that I have to enable?

```
glm::vec3 pos1raw = positionsVec.at((size_t)triangleDataVec.at((size_t)i*XML_TRIANGLE_DATA_COUNT+localIndexOffset++));
glm::vec4 pos1 = glm::vec4(pos1raw.x,pos1raw.y,pos1raw.z,1.0f);
pos1 = partMatrix*pos1;
```

I expected that it would work because people on google used it and it works for them, but im getting

> binary `operator *` cant be used on type `glm::mat4` and `glm::vec4`.

Comment: it seems to work just fine: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/SOaDDO . Have you included all the necessary glm headers? Did you make some defines to affect the behavior?

Comment: @PeterT i have glm/glm.hpp included

Comment: Not enough code. Please, provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)